# How would you write media queries for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: css

If i want

`body {font-size:18 px}` for 1900 and above

`body {font-size:16 px}` for 1024 and 1900

`body {font-size:14 px}` for 768 to 1023

`body {font-size:12 px}` for 320 to 767

`body {font-size:11 px}` for 0 to 320

I just given and example for question.

Answer (score 18):

This should do the work

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)  { body{ font-size: 12px; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)  { body{ font-size: 14px; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) { body{ font-size: 16px; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1900px) { body{ font-size: 18px; } }
```

Comment: Why you are using `only screen` and I saw some people use `max-width`.

Comment: You could always include a different style sheet for each screen resolution too. Or just scale down everything based on EM's. Check this for reference. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Remember you still need selectors inside the media blocks. So it wouldn't just be `font-size:12px` it would like `@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) { body{ font-size:12px } }`

Comment: If i write media queries for other screen sizes and don't write `@media only screen and (min-width: 1900px) {font-size:18px}` and keep in css normally `body {font-size:18px}` will it do the same work?

Comment: If I use your example then is there need to specify the font-size for body outside media queries.?

Answer (score 11):

I love [this blog/website](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), as it is a good resource for CSS3 and nifty tricks:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: So device-width is to use for Mobile and Tablet?

Comment: I think it varies for tablets, as some act like mobile browsers (iPad, for example) and some don't.

Answer (score 3):

Apply this code.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:319px)  { body{font-size:11px}}
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px)  { body{font-size:12px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px)  { body{font-size:14px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1899px) { body{font-size:16px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:1900px) { body{font-size:18px} }
```

Answer (score 3):

Media queries a use for change design of different screens using  CSS

Following different devide for design :https://gist.github.com/sagarjethi/9fb395ee4422cccce625dcde5349fa52

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries. For example your font size for 1024 to 1900 would be set like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1900px){
    body{font-size:16px;}
}
```

For a more thorough explanation see responsive web design: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Will it not override to other lower screen sizes?

Comment: They I have written it, yes. You would need to write other selectors for lesser resolutions or add an `and (min-width: 1200px)`