# Height media query gets applied to all

Tags: css

```css
.im {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

@media screen 
  and (min-height: 600px) 
  and (max-height: 800px) {
    .im {
      margin-top: 228px;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<figure class="im"><img src="a.jpg"></figure>
```

In the above codes the margin of 228 px gets applied to 1080p resolution. What I was looking to achieve is that between 600px to 800px height margin top of 228 should be applied and above 800px height resolution margin top of 300px should be applied.

Comment: Your media query works fine in the snippet - use full screen and slowly reduce the height of your browser, you will see the image moves when it hits your media query and then back again once it has gone past it

Comment: This is working fine. But I was wondering why are you using height? is there a specific reasoning behind this?

Comment: On the actual 1080p laptop it doesn't.

Comment: There is a image which gets cut from the bottom in 720p screen and on 1080p screen there is lot of gap at the bottom after the image. So i was reducing the margin on 720p and increasing it on 1080p screen heights. Would it be better if I do it with 1366 and 1920 width instead of height.

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594876/how-would-you-write-media-queries-for-multiple-screen-sizes

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .im {
    margin-top: 228px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .im {
    margin-top: 300px;
  }
}
```

If the screen is at least 600px wide a margin-top of 228px will be applied. If the screen is at least 800px wide it's like you wrote both one after another which means the latter will be applied